# Can a UK Tier2 dependent work in other EU countries with valid work permit and schengen visa

Tags: united-kingdom, schengen

I am currently working in Belgium with valid Work Permit and Resident Permit. My wife is working in UK with Tier 2 General Visa. Can I get UK Tier2 dependent visa and work in Belgium with my current Belgium work permit and RP?

Comment: If you want to continue working in Belgium, why do you want a Tier 2 dependent visa? You can (and should) only apply for a Tier 2 dependent visa if you intend to reside with your spouse in the UK, which would seem quite difficult if you continue to work in Belgium.

Comment: @Abi Are you looking for a way to be able to visit your wife regularly in the UK?

Comment: @MJeffryes
Yes, I understand that the best suited situation  is to live with my spouse in UK and work there. But I have an ongoing assignment in Belgium and it finishes only on September 2019 and I have to be working in Belgium till that time. But since I can travel betweek Belgium and UK on weekends and holidays, I can meet my family during weekends and holidays till my assignments gets over, and slowly I can find a job in UK and live the whole time with my family. But to do this I would like to get confirmation on the possibility of having both dependent visa and the WP and Rp in Belgium